Token of the HBAR coin (Hedera Hashgraph) in the Stellar network
I want to create a token of the HBAR coin (Hedera Hashgraph) in the Stellar network, with financial support from my side, with the possibility of input and output, everything as it should be, following the example of BTC and ETH tokens, from Ultra Capital, LLC, but I do not have enough knowledge.
https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/asset/BTC-GDPJALI4AZKUU2W426U5WKMAT6CN3AJRPIIRYR2YM54TL2GDWO5O2MZM
https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/asset/ETH-GBFXOHVAS43OIWNIO7XLRJAHT3BICFEIKOJLZVXNT572MISM4CMGSOCC
I figured out how to create a token, I even figured out how to format the stellar.toml file (according to SEP: 0001), but as for SEP: 0006, SEP: 0024, SEP: 0012, it's a complete failure.
The maximum I got to was creating a server to host these files: https://stellar.zhivoglyadov.com.
Can someone help me?
